# sf::Vector2f в классе можно ли?

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор, sfml, инициализация

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>  
class pngg:
{
public:

Texture texture;
Sprite sprite;
sf::Vector2f targetSize(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), 
GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN));
pngg(string way)
{
}
};
```

Ругается на Vector2f [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
хотя если не в классе писать все ок

P.SS
когда выносишь вызов в конструктор пишет:"вызов объекта типа класса без соответствующей функции operator() или функций преобразования указателя в функцию" Почему?

```
class pngg
{
public:

Texture texture;
Sprite sprite;
sf::Vector2f targetSize;
pngg(string way)
{
targetSize(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN));//ошибка

}
};
```

Comment: Потому что внесите эти вызовы GetSysMetrics в конструктор. И, кстати, не делайте скриншоты, а давайте текст. Скопировать код и показать, как и что сделать - я мог бы, но набирать код с нуля?... Вам лень скопировать код в вопрос - так с чего мне будет не лень набирать весь текст в ответе?

Comment: @Harry мне не лень копировать я скриншотами показал,где есть ошибки а где нет.и код на 1200 строк копировать ну такое.

Comment: "код на 1200" - в вопросе следует приводить только минимальный пример, а не вываливать весь свой код

Comment: "...когда выносишь вызов в конструктор"? Какой еще "вызов"? То, что вы пытаетесь сделать, называется **инициализация**. Это никакой не "вызов".

Answer (score 3):

```
sf::Vector2f targetSize(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN));
```

является объявлением функции с невалидными агрументами

Для инициализации полей класса в теле класса (да и во всех остальных случаях тоже) следует использовать синтаксис *direct list initialization*:

```
sf::Vector2f targetSize{GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)};
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
pngg(string way):targetSize(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN),
                            GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN))
{
}
```

Comment: Все работает,а почему как писал я не работает?

Comment: Потому что вы пытались вызвать объект-член класса `targetSize` как функцию, а не инициализировать его.

Answer (score 0):

Непосредственно при объявлении поля в определении класса допускается только `=` синтаксис инициализации или `{}` синтаксис инициализации. Инициализация через `()` не допускается.

В вашем случае, например,

```
sf::Vector2f targetSize{ GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) };

//или

sf::Vector2f targetSize = { GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) };

// или

sf::Vector2f targetSize = sf::Vector2f(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN));
```

В последнем, громоздком, варианте мы используем `()` синтаксис, но через посредство `=` синтаксиса. Иногда и это бывает нужно.